# ASP.net how to make the asp label same CSS style as others?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net

[image: hello]

As you can see from the picture above, all of the labels are created using li except for logout. it uses asp:label. i tried to change the CSS style so it could match the others, but non of them work.
Below are the coding for logout.

```css
       .logout {
         color: #000000;
         display: block;
         font: bold 13px/24px Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
         text-decoration: none;
         text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-size: small;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }
       .navigation {
         float: right;
         list-style: none;
         margin: 28px 0 0;
         padding: 0;
       }
       .navigation li {
         float: left;
         margin-left: 30px;
         position: relative;
         color: #000000;
         height: 20px;
       }
       .navigation li > a {
         color: #000000;
         font: bold 13px/24px Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
         text-decoration: none;
         text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-size: small;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }
       .navigation li.active > a,
       .navigation > a:hover {
         color: #0000FF;
         font-size: small;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }
       .navigation li > div {
         background-color: #888888;
         display: none;
         width: 110px;
         position: absolute;
         z-index: 1;
         left: 0px;
         top: 24px;
       }
       .navigation li:hover > div {
         display: block;
       }
       .navigation li > div a {
         color: #b8c6ac;
         font: bold 13px/24px"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
         display: block;
         text-align: center;
         text-decoration: none;
         text-shadow: none;
       }
       .navigation li > div a:hover {
         color: #fff;
       }
```

```html
<ul class="navigation">
  <li>
    <a href="loginmain.aspx">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li id="sbooking" runat="server">
    <a href="booking.aspx">Booking</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="fac l.aspx">Facilities</a>


  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="ser l.aspx">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="account.aspx">Account</a>
  </li>
  <li class="slogout" runat="server">
    <asp:Label runat="server" OnClick="return confirm('Are you certain you want to logout?');" CssClass="logout"><a href="index.aspx">LogOut</a>
    </asp:Label>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I'll update if more details is needed.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, add more details, especially the css affecting your anchors. Do you have rules like li > a or li a or .navigation a or .navigation > li > a etc? Can you edit your question and reveal more about your css and the HTML generated? You shared your markup, but asp:Label will be modified to something when it reached the browser.

Comment: I guess the label is overwriting styles. In your css, you'll have something like `.navigation{}` , try changing to `.navigation, label{}` to see if that helps. If it does it will be a global change so a better solution is required, but it will at least be a quick test

Comment: nope, nothing has changed dave. updated my info on the css part

Comment: please upload the rendered html in your browser, then one can quickly solve your the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to change the css to:

```
.logout a{
         color: #000000;
         display: block;
         font: bold 13px/24px Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
         text-decoration: none;
         text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-size: small;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Look at CssClass="logout" :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11415448)

Comment: Just to be clear, you added a single letter to the copied code and expected everybody to just notice that tiny change without any explanation?

Comment: To be fair, @RMcLeod, it is an answer to the question - you just have to look really, *really*, **really** closely